# ServingXML: Ressources mapping: get parent node value

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML to JDBC case where I update 2 tables with one xml file using **ServingXML**.
Tables are PRODUIT and PRODUITCATALOGUE.

I am trying to use a field (or in this case attribute) of a parent node in a child node when doing JDBC update.
I have to repeat the NUMPRODUIT attribute on both node as my key in the SQL update.

Is there a way to reuse parent's node NUMPRODUIT in my PRODUITCATLOGUE node?

I have this XML structure:

```
<produit numproduit="18021901">     
        <qteinv>155</qteinv>        
        <produitcatalogue numproduit="18021901">
            <sap_statut>A</sap_statut>                  
        </produitcatalogue>
```

And my mapping in the ressource file:

```
<sx:inverseRecordMapping id="produitMapping">
    <sx:onSubtree path="/produits/produit">
      <sx:flattenSubtree recordType="produit">
        <sx:subtreeFieldMap select="@numproduit" field="numproduit"/>      
        <sx:subtreeFieldMap select="qteinv" field="qteinv"/>                
        <sx:subtreeFieldMap match="produitcatalogue" field="produitscatalogue">
          <sx:flattenSubtree recordType="produitcatalogue">    
            <sx:subtreeFieldMap select="@numproduit" field="numproduit"/> 
            <sx:subtreeFieldMap select="sap_statut" field="sap_statut"/>            
          </sx:flattenSubtree>
        </sx:subtreeFieldMap>
```

I would like to be able to remove numproduit on my produitcatalogue node and run and update 
update produitcatalogue set.. where id = @produit/numproduit

Regards,

M

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by using :

```
 <sx:parameter name="numproduit" select="@numproduit"/>
```

then refering to it with $numproduit in all my other mapping.

New ressource mapping:

```
<sx:inverseRecordMapping id="produitMapping">
    <sx:onSubtree path="/produits/produit">
      <sx:flattenSubtree recordType="produit">
        <sx:parameter name="numproduit" select="@numproduit"/>
        <sx:subtreeFieldMap select="$numproduit" field="numproduit"/>      
        <sx:subtreeFieldMap select="qteinv" field="qteinv"/>                
        <sx:subtreeFieldMap match="produitcatalogue" field="produitscatalogue">
          <sx:flattenSubtree recordType="produitcatalogue">    
            <sx:subtreeFieldMap select="$numproduit" field="numproduit"/> 
            <sx:subtreeFieldMap select="sap_statut" field="sap_statut"/>            
          </sx:flattenSubtree>
        </sx:subtreeFieldMap>
```